# Ember.js bubble event with the same name

Tags: ember.js

I want to bubble an event with the same name from a controller to application:route and pass along parameters.

This doesn't work:

**blog.hbs**

```
<button {{action "createList"}}>Create List</button>
```

**blog_controller.js**

```
actions: {
  createList: function() {
    this.send('createList', 'value1', 'value2');
  }
}
```

**application_route.js**

```
actions: {
  createList: function(param1, param2) {
    console.log('I want to be caught here!!');
  }
}
```

Currently this behaviour only works if I choose different names for the actions in application_route and blog_controller such as (`blogController:createIt` and `applicationRoute:createList`), even though the bubbling order is correct.

How can I get this to work with the same method names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have an action continue up the handler chain *without changing params*, you can simply return true from the action handler.

However, in your case you want to invoke the action with a new set of params. In that case, you should send the action to the controller's `target`. e.g.

**blog_controller.js**

```
actions: {
  createList: function() {
    this.get('target').send('createList', 'value1', 'value2');
  }
}
```